# Facebook Graph API not returning regionalized pages when using App Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a server application monitoring certain Facebook pages for Videos being uploaded. As there is no user involved (server app only), we use an App-Token for our requests.

So far so good, but we have issues with Pages that are only available in certain countries or territories, e.g. "/bitburger" seems to be available in Germany only. I can access the page via API with an User Token (relating to a german user), but my server or even the graph/api explorer (authenticating with an App Token) cannot access the page info.

It will result in an error such as:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'bitburger' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AlDpyo1BjLm"
  }
}
```

Our application is supposed to be global solution that does not care about "regionalized pages" and needs to get the page info (and its published videos) independently from a users location.

Is there any way to achieve this?
So is there a possibility to tell the API-call to ignore regionalized filtering?

User Tokens are not an option (as I said, server app only) and we cannot have a user for every country in the world. We wouldn't even know the right country to begin with :/ It has to work with a location-independant App Token.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Looking forward to any solution.

Thanks and kind regards,
Daniel

// Update:
Thanks for your responses!

I got in touch with Facebook and it is in fact due to "market sites" that only users from this market (country or whatever) have access to. This maps to the API as well and teh App itself does not relate to any market.

The only solution there is (when not having a user to request with), is to get access for your App granted by the page admin. Then you can access the pages info. Unfortunately that does not help for anonymous monitoring.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Any kind of access restriction on an object means you need to use an access token of either a user that can see the object, or a page access token (in case of restricted pages/targeted posts). There is no way to use the app access token here.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but perhaps it has nothing to do with the country but with the fact that's a brewery. Warsteiner, Karlsberg, Carlsberg and Budweiser are working neither. Some other (non brewery) pages are working.

Comment: I think this got something todo with the 'promoting alcohol' flag which makes the page invisible for some countries or states because of law regulation. So this won't be accessible with a server app only token.

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

I got in touch with Facebook and it is in fact due to "market sites" that only users from this market (country or whatever) have access to. This maps to the API as well and teh App itself does not relate to any market.

The only solution there is (when not having a user to request with), is to get access for your App granted by the page admin. Then you can access the pages info. Unfortunately that does not help for anonymous monitoring.